# What are the problems when i ran into Warning .. "Reached Max Size of compiled SQL statement"?

Tags: android, sqlite

If exists, what are the problems if i encounter this, its only a warning and i monitor my database, it doesnt skip anything. But maybe i overlooked.. Im scare that it has serous errors, maybe now or may haunt my app in the future, its really a heavy database heavy.

A definitive answer is what i really need..thanks, i may go to changing all those "WHERE" into `bindArgs  = ?` , like Android suggest, but it will take me alot of time, and i have more priorities than this.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to place all sql queries in the separate class so that u had u open the database ones.
Use Databasehelper classes...

Comment: All selected query is in the same INTENTSERVICE.. it gives me the warning because its too many, its properly done. just too many..